# Lint PHP and only return errors

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'd like to use `php -l` to only return errors and not `No syntax errors detected` messages. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you explain for what purpose? You should be able to examine the return code of the `php -l` command for a successful vs. unsuccessful run. The text output shouldn't matter (although you could parse it for that text).

Comment: I'm setting up my first CI test, and trying to clean up the output. I only care about seeing the errors, because if there are no errors printed I can assume that there were no syntax errors.

Comment: Have you considered a true testing suite? `php -l` is very limited, to syntax errors. You'd want something like `phpunit` for genuine CI testing.

Comment: Yea, that's on my list for something to look in to, I just wanted something very basic for now 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through some crafty Googling I was able to locate this set of commands:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P4 php -l -n | (! grep -v "No syntax errors detected" )
```

It loops through all files in the current folder and only outputs errors, and causes a CI build to fail if an error occurs.

Source: https://gist.github.com/mathiasverraes/3096500#gistcomment-2570105

Answer (score 0):

This is a little simpler.

find . -type f -iname '*.php' -exec php -l {} ; | grep -v "No syntax errors detected"

Comment: To make this work, it requires bash set -o pipefail